# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError :org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/ctextensionlist in groovy

Tags: excel, groovy, soapui, xssf

I am trying to access the existing Excel sheet and trying to create a new sheet and update the sheet with some values,On executing i am getting the below error for line "rowHeader.createCell((short) count ).setCellValue("test1");"
Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError :org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/ctextensionlist error on executing the below code

Foll are the list of jars i used

commons-codec-1.9

commons-logging-1.1.3

commons-net-3.3-ftp

junit-4.12,

jxl-2.6.6-sources,

jxl-2.6,

log4j-1.2.17,

MasterExcelReport,

ojdbc6,

poi-3.13-20150929,

poi-3.15-beta1,

poi-examples-3.13-20150929,

poi-examples-3.15-beta1,

poi-excelant-3.13-20150929,

poi-excelant-3.15-beta1,

poi-ooxml-3.5-beta5,

poi-ooxml-3.13-20150929,

poi-ooxml-3.15-beta1,

poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13-20150929,

poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15-beta1,

poi-scratchpad-3.13-20150929,

poi-scratchpad-3.15-beta1,

postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41,

sqljdbc42,
xmlbeans-2.6.0

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import javax.xml.datatype.*;
import javax.xml.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.lang.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
  import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;



def fname = new Date().format("MM-dd-YYYY-HH-mm-a-z")
def TimeStamp = context.expand('${General_Properties#Current_Date}')
def destination_path_File = context.expand('${General_Properties#Destination_path}')
def destination_path = destination_path_File + "_" + TimeStamp
def Request = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Alliance_Ser")
//def FileName = "Individual Coverages Premium Result"
def Vehical = context.expand('${General_Properties#Alliance_Vehicals}')
def Driver = context.expand('${General_Properties#Alliance_Drivers}')
def FolderName = context.expand('${General_Properties#StateCode}')
def FileName = FolderName + "_Result_Status and Total Premiums_" + Vehical + "_Vehicals_" + Driver + "_Drivers"
def ResultPath = destination_path + "\\" + FolderName + "\\" + FileName + "_" + TimeStamp + ".xls"
log.info ResultPath


FileInputStream fileIn = new  FileInputStream(new File(ResultPath))
 XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileIn);

 XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Coverage_Resp_report");
short count = 0;
Row rowHeader = sheet.createRow((short)count);
rowHeader.createCell((short) count ).setCellValue("test1");
//rowHeader.createCell((short) count ).setCellValue("Test2");

FileOutputStream fileOut =new FileOutputStream(new File(ResultPath));  //Open FileOutputStream to write updates
workbook.write(fileOut); //write changes
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: What is your classpath?

Comment: I am doing this in soapUI tool .I don't define a class path ,I just import

Comment: Other can't image that unless you specify that. Any ways, what libraries have you copied under soapui?

Comment: poi-ooxml-3.5-beta5

Comment: Just that one file? Can you list all the jar files which are available under the `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext` directory.

Comment: commons-codec-1.9,
commons-logging-1.1.3,
commons-net-3.3-ftp,
junit-4.12,
jxl-2.6.6-sources,
jxl-2.6,
log4j-1.2.17,
MasterExcelReport,
ojdbc6,
poi-3.13-20150929,
poi-3.15-beta1,
poi-examples-3.13-20150929,
poi-examples-3.15-beta1,
poi-excelant-3.13-20150929,
poi-excelant-3.15-beta1,
poi-ooxml-3.5-beta5,
poi-ooxml-3.13-20150929,
poi-ooxml-3.15-beta1,
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13-20150929,
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15-beta1,
poi-scratchpad-3.13-20150929,
poi-scratchpad-3.15-beta1,
postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41,
sqljdbc42,
xmlbeans-2.6.0

Comment: Would you mind updating the same in the question as this is not readable.

Comment: I have updated the same in the question

Answer (score 2):

After copying 'ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar' file in lib folder, issue was resolved